# Create polygon grid based on spatial points (WGS84) with R

Tags: r, polygon, coordinates, wgs84, grids-graticules

**Initial problem:**
I am currently trying to create a spatial grid in which each cell is centered on predefined spatial points. These spatial points are projected in the WGS84 international coordinate system.

I am starting with a long/lat dataframe containing around 8000 point-location over France ([data available here](https://github.com/mgarnault/Help)).

```
df=read.table("~/centroids.csv",sep=",",header=T)
plot(df$longitude,df$latitude,pch=".")
```

[image: centroidsPlotFrance]

I want to compute "tile" polygons that will fill the entire space around these points. Something like in [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/273233/create-spatial-polygon-grid-from-spatial-points-in-r), with each point of *df* at the center of tiles, such as :

[image: exampleTileCenteredOnPoints]

I tried several methods from the sf and raster package such as : st_make_grid(), rasterFromXYZ() combined with rasterToPolygons() that I saw in [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/298972/converting-lat-long-and-values-to-raster-doesnt-project-correctly), or even the basic raster() using gridded() that I saw on [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20018/how-can-i-convert-data-in-the-form-of-lat-lon-value-into-a-raster-file-using-r/20052). I also tried to use gBuffer() such as in [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/220358/real-dimensions-of-square-buffers). But without any sucess... I am always fighting against projection or non-regular/planar coordinates errors !

Once I will be able compute those tiles (or polygons), I want to store them in a simple feature object (from the sf package). Within this sf object: each polygon will correspond to a cell of the final spatial grid; each polygon will be centered on a spatial point from *df*; and each polygon will inherit the ID of the point (from *df*) on which it is centered.

Is that possible ???

Comment: Those points don't look to be on a regular grid - look at just Corsica for example - are you expecting a regular polygon grid as output? Those points might be on a regular grid in another coordinate system but it seems to break down in places.

Comment: I agree, points are not on regular grid. But i wanted to find a way to shape polygon that could fill the space around each point (the "grid" will not be regular for sure). Do you think this is impossible ? Maybe I have to find the one projection in which those points are in a regular grid ? Maybe this projection does not even exists...

Comment: I tried with different coordinate systems, and I found out that your points, when displayed in epsg:27572 (NTF Lambert Zone II), form a regular grid of 8km x 8km, with at most around 2-3 meters of error across the whole country. So I guess generating your grid in epsg:27572 would overlay quite well.

Answer (score 2):

**Final solution:**

```
library("sp")
library("sf")
library("raster")
library("parallel")
library("ggplot2")

df=read.table("~/centroids.csv",sep=",",header=TRUE)

df2=df
coordinates(df2)=~longitude+latitude
proj4string(df2)=CRS("+init=epsg:4326") # points are initially projected in WGS84
df2=spTransform(df2,CRS("+init=epsg:27572")) # points are distributed on an approximatly regular grid in NTF Lambert Zone II (thank you @FSimardGIS !!!)

grid=points2grid(df2,tolerance=0.00587692) # 0.00587692 is the minimum value I found by hand, by trial and error
grid=as.data.frame(SpatialGrid(grid)) 
coordinates(grid)=~longitude+latitude

grid=rasterFromXYZ(grid)
grid=rasterToPolygons(grid)
grid=st_as_sf(grid)
st_crs(grid)=27572
grid=st_transform(grid,crs="+init=epsg:4326") # re-projection of the grid in the initial projection of df values which are in WGS84

cl=makeCluster(spec=(detectCores()-1)) # parallel computation in order to know which cells from grid actually contain points from df
clusterEvalQ(cl,library("sf"))
clusterExport(cl,c("grid","df"))
df$gridLoc=parApply(cl,df,1,function(row){
  pnt=st_sfc(st_point(c(row["longitude"],row["latitude"])),crs=4326)
  id=row["ID"]
  return(as.numeric(st_intersects(pnt,grid)))
})
stopCluster(cl)

grid=grid[df$gridLoc,] # selection of cells from grid that actually contain points from df
grid$layer=df$ID # transfert the ID of centroids to the coresponding cell of the grid

x11()
ggplot()+
  geom_sf(aes(fill=layer),col="black",data=grid)+
  geom_point(aes(x=longitude,y=latitude),pch=21,fill="white",col="black",size=.9,data=df)+
  scale_fill_gradient2(low="#47fe44",mid="#f8fe44",high="#fe4444",midpoint=5000)
```

Which give this nice plot (color layer corresponds to the initial ID of spatial points in *df*, white dots correspond to the initial centroids from *df*):
[image]

Even if some points seem to be a bit off-center from the cell, its only a plotting artifact due to the high resolution, as we can see here with increased zoom on Corsica:
[image]

The answer to this post is therefore : (1) find the right projection in which points form a regular grid; (2) use gridded() or points2grid() to compute the regular grid; (3) transform the grid points into a raster using rasterFromXYZ(); (4) transform the raster into polygons using rasterToPolygons(); (5) re-project the polygons into the initial projection using st_transform(); (6 optional) if you do not want to keep all created cells within the grid, use st_intersects() to find which cells actually contains initial points.

Thanks a lot for your advices !

**Testing the grid centroid offsets:**
I can compute the centroids of the grid and compare their location to the initial centroids:

```
estimatedCentroids=st_centroid(grid) # new centroids from grid

coordinates(df)=~longitude+latitude
proj4string(df)=CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
trueCentroids=st_centroid(st_as_sf(df)) # initial centroids from df

centroidsOffset=st_distance(estimatedCentroids,trueCentroids,by_element=TRUE) # compute distance of each pair of centroids between grid and df

hist(centroidsOffset,nclass=100)
```

With the final solution that I present above, I therefore make an average error of 550m (range from 170m to 900m):
[image]

If I well understand the methodology, this is due to the use of the points2grid() function with a tolerance parameter of 0.00587692. Which means that points are not distributed on a true regular grid, even in the NTF Lambert Zone II projection (which still the better I found).

Comment: Interesting. When I tested it on my side, the errors were more in the range of 2-3 meters. The points really closely matched a regular grid. But I generated my grid from scratch in epsg:27572, not with the points to grid function. The grid was 8000 x 8000, with a range of (0, 1240000, 1605000, 2685000)

Comment: Could this difference be due to the fact that I computed distances in the initial projection (WGS84), while you did in the Lambert II projection ? Or did you spot an error in my code (such as when I used the point2grid() function that I am not very familiar with) ? Also, I am curious about how you generated your grid “from scratch” as you said ?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how the points2grid algorithm works, but when I tested, I made a new grid with [this method](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/273248/82947), but with the size and extent parameters that I mentioned above, and in Lambert II. Then I checked the distances in Lambert II as well, and all the points were within 3 meters, more or less, of the grid centroids. I would try it with that kind of simple grid, it might give you better results, since from my observations and test, I know it closely matches that specific grid.

Comment: That is indeed much better. With your handmade grid the mean distance between true centroids and estimated centroids ranges from 0 to 5m (in Lambert II, as in WGS84), with an average offset of 2.17m. Therefore I will not use the points2grid() method after all... Thanks a lot for your help !